# How do i remove favorites folders from my ipad on ios 9.1?

Tags: ipad, safari, bookmarks

In my list of bookmarks, i have several empty folders labeled favorites. How do i get rid of these? The edit button doesnt allow it to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you're also syncing your iCloud bookmarks to PC and didn't think it was relevant.

I fixed this issue for myself earlier today by going into Chrome on my PC and deleting all the multiple "Bookmarks Bar" folders I found. It seems a new one was created any time a change was made in the iOS Favorites folder, and I guess when Chrome would then try to sync its own bookmarks back to iCloud, that's when it would create the duplicate folders on the iPad and iPhone.

If the issue comes back then I may just disable iCloud bookmark syncing on the PC entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are in Safari. If you're looking at the grid of favorites (like you would see when you open a new tab), you can tap and hold on the icons to delete them.

If you are looking at the list of favorites (like you would see when accessing your reading list with the book icon next to the address/search bar), the edit button should make a red circle with a line in the center appear. Tap that, and a red delete button should appear.

If neither of those are working for you, you may be experiencing a bug, though both of them work for me on my iPad (4th-gen) with iOS 9.1. Good luck!

Comment: Thx, but nothing works that u suggested, hence my question. I also have 4 th gen ipad w ios 9.1. Hard restart diesnt work either. I'm stumped. It's too bad I'm driven to organized neatness.